# Add text label near the position arrows in chart.Posn () function of blotter

Tags: r, charts, quantmod, quantstrat, blotter

Is it possible to add texts like "BUY" and "SELL" near the green and red arrows in chart.Posn() function. (not with manual trial of coordinates, I need an automatic solution) I have changed the source code of function a bit and increased the size of arrows:

[image]

If a minimum reproducible example is needed, I can provide but this is a basic question for graphical parameters of R.

Your help is appreciated.

**Edit for a minimum reproducible example:**

```
library(quantstrat)

start_date <- as.Date("2018-02-02")
end_date <- as.Date("2018-09-24")
init_date <- as.Date("2018-01-01")
init_equity <- "50000"
adjustment <- TRUE
symbol <- "AAPL"


getSymbols(symbol, src = "yahoo",
       from = start_date, to=end_date,
       adjust = adjustment)


portfolio.st <- "basic_port"
account.st <- "basic_account"
strategy.st <- "basic_strategy"


rm.strat(portfolio.st)
rm.strat(account.st)

stock(symbol, currency = currency("USD"), multiplier = 1)
initPortf(name = portfolio.st, symbols = symbol, initDate =init_date)

initAcct(name = account.st, portfolios = portfolio.st, 
         initDate = init_date, initEq =init_equity)
initOrders(portfolio.st, symbol, init_date)
strategy(strategy.st, store = TRUE)



add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st, name = "SMA",
              arguments = list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n=10),
              label ="nFast")


add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st, name = "SMA",
              arguments = list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n=30),
              label = "nSlow")

add.signal(strategy = strategy.st, 
           name= "sigCrossover",
           arguments =  list(columns = c("nFast", "nSlow"),
                             relationship = "gte"),
           label = "longenter")

add.signal(strategy = strategy.st,
           name= "sigCrossover", 
           arguments =  list(columns = c("nFast",
                                         "nSlow"), 
                             relationship = "lt"),
           label = "longexit")

#Add rules for entering positions
#enter long position
add.rule(strategy.st, 
         name = "ruleSignal", 
         arguments = list(sigcol = "longenter",
                          sigval = TRUE,
                          orderqty = 100,
                          ordertype = "market",
                          orderside = "long",
                          orderset= "ocolong",
                          prefer = "Close",
                          TxnFees = -.8,
                          replace = FALSE),
         type = "enter",
         label = "EnterLong")



#stoploss long
add.rule(strategy = strategy.st, 
         name = "ruleSignal",
         arguments = list(sigcol = "longenter",
                          sigval = TRUE,
                          TxnFees=-.8,
                          replace = FALSE, 
                          orderside = "long", 
                          ordertype = "stoplimit",
                          orderqty = "all", 
                          tmult = TRUE,
                          prefer = "Close",
         order.price=quote(as.numeric(mktdata$AAPL.Low[timestamp])),
                          orderset="ocolong"), 
         type = "chain", parent = "EnterLong", 
         path.dep=TRUE, 
         label = "stop_loss_long", 
         enabled=TRUE)


#Apply strategy
applyStrategy(strategy.st, portfolios = portfolio.st,debug = TRUE)
updatePortf(portfolio.st)
updateAcct(account.st)
updateEndEq(account.st)

st<- "2018-05-01 00:00:00"
fn<-"2018-06-20 00:00:00"
chart.Posn(portfolio.st, Symbol = symbol, Dates = paste(st, fn, sep="::"))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please share some code you tried and data using `dput`?

Comment: I edited. Thanks. I want a text for "BUY" and "SELL" near green and red arrows for positions.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the base R function `text` where you can specify the position and the label like this:

```r
library(quantstrat)

start_date <- as.Date("2018-02-02")
end_date <- as.Date("2018-09-24")
init_date <- as.Date("2018-01-01")
init_equity <- "50000"
adjustment <- TRUE
symbol <- "AAPL"


getSymbols(symbol, src = "yahoo",
           from = start_date, to=end_date,
           adjust = adjustment)
#> [1] "AAPL"


portfolio.st <- "basic_port"
account.st <- "basic_account"
strategy.st <- "basic_strategy"


rm.strat(portfolio.st)
rm.strat(account.st)

stock(symbol, currency = currency("USD"), multiplier = 1)
#> [1] "AAPL"
initPortf(name = portfolio.st, symbols = symbol, initDate =init_date)
#> [1] "basic_port"

initAcct(name = account.st, portfolios = portfolio.st, 
         initDate = init_date, initEq =init_equity)
#> [1] "basic_account"
initOrders(portfolio.st, symbol, init_date)
strategy(strategy.st, store = TRUE)



add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st, name = "SMA",
              arguments = list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n=10),
              label ="nFast")
#> [1] "basic_strategy"


add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st, name = "SMA",
              arguments = list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n=30),
              label = "nSlow")
#> [1] "basic_strategy"

add.signal(strategy = strategy.st, 
           name= "sigCrossover",
           arguments =  list(columns = c("nFast", "nSlow"),
                             relationship = "gte"),
           label = "longenter")
#> [1] "basic_strategy"

add.signal(strategy = strategy.st,
           name= "sigCrossover", 
           arguments =  list(columns = c("nFast",
                                         "nSlow"), 
                             relationship = "lt"),
           label = "longexit")
#> [1] "basic_strategy"

#Add rules for entering positions
#enter long position
add.rule(strategy.st, 
         name = "ruleSignal", 
         arguments = list(sigcol = "longenter",
                          sigval = TRUE,
                          orderqty = 100,
                          ordertype = "market",
                          orderside = "long",
                          orderset= "ocolong",
                          prefer = "Close",
                          TxnFees = -.8,
                          replace = FALSE),
         type = "enter",
         label = "EnterLong")
#> [1] "basic_strategy"



#stoploss long
add.rule(strategy = strategy.st, 
         name = "ruleSignal",
         arguments = list(sigcol = "longenter",
                          sigval = TRUE,
                          TxnFees=-.8,
                          replace = FALSE, 
                          orderside = "long", 
                          ordertype = "stoplimit",
                          orderqty = "all", 
                          tmult = TRUE,
                          prefer = "Close",
                          order.price=quote(as.numeric(mktdata$AAPL.Low[timestamp])),
                          orderset="ocolong"), 
         type = "chain", parent = "EnterLong", 
         path.dep=TRUE, 
         label = "stop_loss_long", 
         enabled=TRUE)
#> [1] "basic_strategy"


#Apply strategy
applyStrategy(strategy.st, portfolios = portfolio.st,debug = TRUE)
#> [1] "2018-04-19 02:00:00 AAPL 100 @ 42.8836602855443"
#> [1] "2018-04-20 02:00:00 AAPL -100 @ 42.3376887640763"
#> [1] "2018-05-09 02:00:00 AAPL 100 @ 46.4970046592104"
#> [1] "2018-06-19 02:00:00 AAPL -100 @ 45.9659223045418"
#> [1] "2018-07-17 02:00:00 AAPL 100 @ 47.6952277265372"
#> [1] "2018-07-30 02:00:00 AAPL -100 @ 47.1346935681311"
#> $basic_port
#> $basic_port$AAPL
#> <environment: 0x7fa52528db88>
updatePortf(portfolio.st)
#> [1] "basic_port"
updateAcct(account.st)
#> Warning in rbind(deparse.level, ...): mismatched types: converting objects to
#> numeric
#> [1] "basic_account"
updateEndEq(account.st)
#> [1] "basic_account"

st<- "2018-05-01 00:00:00"
fn<-"2018-06-20 00:00:00"
chart.Posn(portfolio.st, Symbol = symbol, Dates = paste(st, fn, sep="::"))
text(8, 1000, "BUY")
text(35, 1000, "SELL")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much! What does these (8, 1000) and (35,1000) positioning stands for?

Comment: @SerhatAkay, these are x and y coordinates. You can change them to whatever youu want.

Comment: how did you find the exact numbers? I could not see those numbers on the graph.

Comment: @SerhatAkay, I did trial and error. So you can change the numbers to different positions if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your support but I need a dynamic solution because every time the positioning of the arrows will change. This code will be automated.